# Identity Server 4: Support Refresh Token for password grant type

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have implemented Identity Server 4 with a password grant type flow. I would like to know if it is possible to implement a refresh token so the client does not have to resend the username and password when the auth token expires. If so, can I please have some documentation.

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/refresh_tokens.html):

> Refresh tokens are supported for the following flows: authorization code, hybrid and resource owner password credential flow. The clients needs to be explicitly authorized to request refresh tokens by setting `AllowOfflineAccess` to `true`

So in theory you should be able to implement it, by setting the required parameters.

Just as an FYI, there is something else. Again from the [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html#resource-owner-password):

> The resource owner password grant type allows to request tokens on behalf of a user by sending the user’s name and password to the token endpoint. This is so called “non-interactive” authentication and is **generally not recommended**.

So if you have the chance to use another grant type - I would advise you so. If not, the answer to your question is - yes, you can use refresh tokens with the Password grant type